# How to connect ms sql database using perl in Windows?

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc

I want to connect ms sql database through perl language. The following steps are I made.

- I've created a database table in the name "SampleDb"
- Configured ODBC and I've set name for sql server driver as "SampleDb"
- Now I've tried to connect as follows,

,

```
my $dbs = "dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={SampleDb}";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dbs, "username", "password");
```

But Now I got the following error

```
DBI connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={SampleDB}','username',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000)
```

**How to solve this ? or
How to Connect ms sql using perl through ODBC ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has already been answered (and accepted !!). Just providing detailed steps for connecting MSSQL server from perl running on Linux using ODBC.

Before you get into perl stuff, you need to install and configure odbc environment on the Linux box.

Install below packages:

```
Fedora:
    unixODBC-devel.i686 
    unixODBC.i686
    AND
    freetds.i686 
    freetds-devel.i686 
    freetds-doc.i686
Ubuntu:
    unixodbc 
    unixodbc-dev
    AND
    freetds-bin 
    freetds-common  
    freetds-dev
    tdsodbc
```

After these packages are installed we MUST be able to use `freetds` to test authentication network authentication with the MS SQL server.

```
root@ubuntu:/home# tsql -S <db_host_name> -p 1433 -U perluser -P password
locale is "en_IN"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
1>
```

If above fails, then check the MSSQL db permission for this user. Also check MSSQL logs. Do not proceed until you run above command successfully. Also, failure of above command has nothing to do with the `unixodbc` OR `freetds` configuration.

Configure the `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` and `freetds.conf` files.

`/etc/odbc.ini` will contain the DSN information:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# cat /etc/odbc.ini 
[odbc-test]
Description     = test
Driver          = ms-sql
Servername      = ms-sql
Database        = <db_name>
UID             = perluser
Port            = 1433
```

- Please note that, the `Driver` field refers to `/etc/odbcinst.ini` context named `[ms-sql]`.
- The `Servername` field refers to the `/etc/freetds.conf` context that I also named `[ms-sql]`.
- `Database` field is optional but I am using it as I want to connect to a particular Database.

`/etc/odbcinst.ini` file contains the Driver information:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini 
[ms-sql]
Description     = TDS Conection
Driver          = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
FileUsage       = 1
```

- The `odbcinst.ini` file simply directs the `odbc.ini` file to the appropriate driver.
- The `Driver` and `Setup` entries for Fedora is `/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so` and `/usr/lib/libtdsS.so` respectively.
- Also, for 64-bit Linux box, it would be `Driver64` and `Setup64` instead of `Driver` and `Setup` respectively.

Configure `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` ( `/etc/freetds.conf` for Fedora). It contains TDS information. Here is mine:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# tail  /etc/freetds/freetds.conf 
[ms-sql]
        host = <db_host_name>
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
        dump file = /var/log/freetds.log
```

- Please note that, above context name `[ms-sql]` is the value of `Servername` in `odbc.ini`.

Test the configuration by connecting the MSSQL server using `isql` command:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# isql -v odbc-test perluser password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

- The `odbc-test` portion of the `isql` command was defined in the `odbc.ini` file.
- You HAVE to receive above output which says `Connected!`. If you don’t, then there is some problem in your configuration and go through all the above steps again.

Now,

- Install Perl [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm) module.
- Install [`DBD::ODBC`](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.45/ODBC.pm) module .

Then use the ODBC in your perl code as below:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect ('dbi:ODBC:odbc-test', 'perluser', 'password');
```

Hope This Helps.

Comment: @slayebylucifer I tried but it show `[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`

Answer (score 2):

**This is for connecting MSSQL using perl in Windows.**

Instead of ODBC, try OLEDB. The following code will help you.

```
my $host = 'sample\sql';
my $database = 'SampleDB';
my $user = 'sa';
my $auth = 'password';

$dsn  = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;";
$dsn .= "Server=$host;Database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:$dsn",$user,$auth,{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

Reference [How to connect Ms Sql using Perl](http://dolio.lh.net/~apw/doc/HOWTO/HOWTO-Connect_Perl_to_SQL_Server.pdf)

Comment: I cannot understand why changing to use DBD::ADO fixes the issue. There is nothing wrong about using DBD::ODBC and the reasons for the error shown can be found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328306